# How to convert addEventListener function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new in jQuery and would like to convert this javascript code in jQuery

```
var trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
for (var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
     trigger[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (this == trigger[0]) {
            position = '1';
        } else if (this == trigger[1]) {
            position = '2';
        }
        .......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var trigger = $('.item');
trigger.click(function() {
  if (this == trigger[0]) {
    position = '1';
    alert('first clicked');
  } else if (this == trigger[1]) {
    position = '2';
    alert('second clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
```

And about the error you are receiving:

`Error "Uncaught TypeError: sizeListItem[i].on is not a function"`

Please post your whole code in your post, or drop it on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

A long list of `if{..}else{...}` is a codesmell, no matter if you're using vanilla JS or jQuery. *That* is the bit you should be solving, and jQuery makes that easier using [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$('ul').on('click','.item',function(){
  var position = $(this).index()+1;
  console.log(position);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item1</li>
  <li class="item">Item2</li>
  <li class="item">Item3</li>
  <li class="item">Item4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow jquery sintax to do that. If you have more than 2 selectors, do loop in jquery is the same of javascript.

```
 $('.item:nth-of-type(1) ').click(function() {
  position = '1';
 });
 $('.item:nth-of-type(2) ').click(function() {
      position = '2';
 });
```